# How to write coordinates in keypoint?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got coordinates of one pixel of my image (for example `int i,j;`), how can I write them into a vector like the following one?

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoint_object;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html), I see there is a constructor for KeyPoint that allows insertion of your indices. However it requires an additional parameter size, and I don't know what you need that to be.

However, the general idea would be this:

```
keypoint_object.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j,0));
```

Here, `i` and `j` are implicitly cast to `float` (I assume that is what you require) and the third argument is `0` (as it's mandatory) -- you probably want a more sensible argument here.

Comment: another question, as i can see: KeyPoint(float x, float y, float _size, float _angle=-1, float _response=0, int _octave=0, int _class_id=-1); that means 3d argument should be "size", which size? cause "0"-parametr doesn't work.

Comment: @fen1ksss: You should probably post that as a separate question. I cannot answer it, because I only know the *syntax* of the interface. There are probably some OpenCV experts here that know the *semantics*, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a class:

```
class Coordinate{
public:
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

...

```
vector <Coordinate> name;

Coordinate coordinate;
coordinate.x = 1~
coordinate.y = 5~

name.push_back(coordinate);
```

This is what are you looking for? I hope this will help you!

Comment: almost, but is there a way, to use exactly default KeyPoint class? cause i need it later?

Comment: later will be `SurfFeatureDetector detector (400); 
detector.detect (img, keypoint_object); 
where std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoint_object`